# Why can't arrays be used in multiple foreach loops?

Tags: php, arrays

This is a simple question yet I'm unable to find an answer to this. I'm not looking for corrections to my code, simply education regarding this issue.

The array is defined before the first foreach begins so I can use it outside of the loop.

```
$arrayVar = array();

foreach ($variables as $key => $variable){
  $arrayVar = array(
    'name' => $squad['full_name'],
    'position' => $squad['position']
  ); 
}
```

This populates the array with data. However, when used in another loop, the array resets instead of appending to the end.

EDIT: John's answer resolves the issue. A simple inclusion of square brackets has saved me around 1000 lines.

Comment: When talking about code that doesn't behave as expected, you should include a [mcve] - a short piece of code that actually demonstrates the problem, with the output you expected, and the output you actually got. Here, you've shown us the code you say is working OK, and the description of the problem is not very clear. It's therefore hard to tell if the answer you've been given addresses the problem you thought you had, or just points out a different problem in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep overwriting your array in every iteration instead of *appending* to it.

```
$arrayVar = array();

foreach ($variables as $key => $variable){
  $arrayVar[] = array( // <= Add to array instead of overwriting it
    'name' => $squad['full_name'],
    'position' => $squad['position']
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, I appreciate the insight. So, I feel like array_push is what I should be using in remaining loops.

Comment: @M.Whitmore 1) The `[]` notation shown in this answer is equivalent to `array_push`, but more commonly used for its conciseness. 2) It's not about using it in "remaining loops", it's about _the loop you've shown us here_ being incorrect.

Comment: @IMSoP many thanks, I missed the notation initially from John's answer.